# Wrong answer with equation in python

Tags: python, math, python-2.7

try it with [Wolphram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=4%2F3+%2a+6.67%2a1e-11%2a3.14%2a6378000%2a5515) - this is correct result.

try it with python 2.7.x:

```
u = 4/3 * 6.67*1e-11*3.14*6378000*5515
print (u)
```

Answer would be 7.36691253546

What is here incorrect?

Comment: `4/3` performs integer division in Python 2. Try `4.0/3` instead.

Answer (score 6):

Integer division. `4/3` evaluates to 1 as it is rounded down.

Use `4.0` instead to force floating point arithmetic:

```
>>> 4.0/3 * 6.67*1e-11*3.14*6378000*5515
9.822550047279998
```

or use Python 3, where floating point division is the default, or use `from __future__ import division` to achieve the same in Python 2:

```
Python 2.7.5 (default, May 22 2013, 12:00:45) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2336.11.00)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from __future__ import division
>>> 4/3 * 6.67*1e-11*3.14*6378000*5515
9.822550047279998
```

This behaviour is documented under the [Binary arithmetic operators section](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#binary-arithmetic-operations):

> The `/` (division) and `//` (floor division) operators yield the quotient of their arguments. The numeric arguments are first converted to a common type. Plain or long integer division yields an integer of the same type; the result is that of mathematical division with the ‘floor’ function applied to the result. Division by zero raises the `ZeroDivisionError` exception.

See [PEP 238](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0238/) about why this behaviour was changed in Python 3, and for a reference to the `from __future__ import division` statement.

Comment: 4/3 evaluates to 1, not to 0

Answer (score 3):

The problem is the integer division `4/3` in Python 2.7

```
>>> print (4.0/3) * 6.67*1e-11*3.14*6378000*5515
9.82255004728
```

In Python 3 (where `/` is float division and `//` is integer division) This would have worked without changing it to `4.0/3`, alternatively you may use

```
from __future__ import division
```